# path of php.ini file in magento folder structure

Tags: php

i want to find the path of php.ini file

we saw somewhere it's here : /usr/local/lib/php.ini

where we can find the path of "/usr/local/lib/".

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its basic knowledge, answered a million times on the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file in magento root: phpinfo.php and enter this:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Go to this page, you can see which php.ini is being taken.

Comment: Or you can type `php --ini` from the terminal.

Comment: Warning: Having PHP info exposed on a live server is a security risk